# Eloquent model has no defaults

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have an Eloquent model and a matching migration. I'm having issues with default values not being set. I'm using MySQL.

Migration:

```
    Schema::create('cert_jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('key')->unique();
        $table->enum('task', [CertJob::TASK_CREATE, CertJob::TASK_REVOKE]);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('input_file')->nullable();
        $table->string('output_file')->nullable();
        $table->enum('format', CertJob::CERT_FORMATS);
        $table->integer('queue_job_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('status')->default(\App\CertJobStatus::PENDING);
        $table->text('error')->nullable();
        $table->integer('attempts')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('downloaded')->default(false);
        // created_at && updated_at
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Model:

```
class CertJob extends Model
{
    //...

    protected $fillable = [
        'task', 'input_file', 'format', 'status', 'attempts', 'key',
    ];

    protected $visible = [
        'uuid', 'task', 'owner', 'format', 'error', 'job_status',
        'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'job_status', 'uuid', 'owner'
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        // Auto inject by key instead of ID
        return 'key';
    }

    public function user(){}

    private function makePath(String $file){}

    public function getInputFile(){}

    public function getOutputFile(){}

    public function getJobStatusAttribute(){}

    public function getUuidAttribute(){}

    public function getOwnerAttribute(){}

    public function pushToQueue(){}


    public static function make(string $format, User $owner, UploadedFile $certFile) : CertJob
    {
        // Validate
        $format = strtoupper($format);
        if (!in_array($format, CertJob::CERT_FORMATS)) {
            $format = CertJob::CERT_FORMATS[0];
        }

        // Create our cert job
        $certJob = new CertJob([
            'key' => bin2hex(random_bytes(16)),
            'task' => 'CREATE',
            'format' => $format,
        ]);

        $certJob->user()->associate($owner);
        $certJob->save();

        Log::info($certJob->task . ' Cert Job ' . $certJob->key . ' Created for User:' . $owner->email);

        // Save input file with certJob ID in filename (easier to identify)
        $inputFile = $certFile->storeAs('create', 'job_' . str_pad($certJob->id, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.' . $format, CertJob::FS_DISK);
        $certJob->input_file = $inputFile;
        // Delete tmp
        Storage::delete($certFile);

        $certJob->save();
        return $certJob;
    }
}
```

When I create a CertJob with the CertJob::make function, the resulting object does not have `downloaded`, `status`, or `attempts` properties.

I've tried calling `fresh()` with zero change. Why are the defaults from the migration not propagating to the model? Am I doing this wrong?

For what it's worth, I found this issue while testing my model. The only magic I have in the test class is `use DatabaseMigrations;`.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Wow I figured it out. I had to return the results of `fresh()`.

So at the end of that `make` function, I changed `return $certJob` to `return $certJob->refresh()` and it works now.